# VB.NET Replace Lines & Task Killer

Tags: vb.net

i have two questions for my VB.NET Project that is codded on .netFrameWork 4.0

1:
For example i have text file "textfile1.txt" now program need to find line "//This Line" and replace next line after "//This Line"

example:
In textfile1.txt

```
//This Line
Some Code here
```

I need to replace Some Code here with text from TextBox1.text

2: 
I have text file "MultiLineTextBox1" now program need to kill process by name from MultiTextBox1 line by line

example: 
In MultiLineTextBox1

```
notepad
mspain
```

Notepad and MSPaint need to be killed...

Comment: I recommend splitting this "single" question into two separate questions.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on what I understood from your question this is what you are after. Now if there are any adjustments to make then feel free to comment.

```
Private Sub Question1()
    Dim list = File.ReadAllLines("yourFilePath").ToList()
    Dim itemCount = list.Count

    For i As Integer = 0 To itemCount - 1
        If list(i) = "//This Line" AndAlso Not ((i + 1) > itemCount) Then
            list(i + 1) = TextBox1.Text
        End If
    Next

    KillProcesses(list)
End Sub

Private Sub Question2()
    Dim list = TextBox1.Text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()
    KillProcesses(list)
End Sub

Private Sub KillProcesses(items As List(Of String))
    For Each item As String In items.Where(Function(listItem) listItem <> "//This Line") ' Exclude redundant text
        Dim processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(item)

        For Each process As Process In processes
            Try
                process.Kill()                         
            Catch
                ' Do your error handling here
            End Try
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**UPDATE: Code below is an updated version to reflect the changes requested in the comments below**

```
Private Sub Question1()
    Dim list = File.ReadAllLines("YourFilePath").ToList()
    Dim itemCount = list.Count

    For i As Integer = 0 To itemCount - 1
        If list(i) = "//This Line" Then
            If (i + 1 > itemCount - 1) Then ' Check if the current item is the last one in the list, if it is then add the text to the list
                list.Add(TextBox1.Text)
            Else ' An item exists, so just update its value
                list(i + 1) = TextBox1.Text
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' Write the list back to the file
    File.WriteAllLines(Application.StartupPath & "\test.txt", list)

    KillProcesses(list)
End Sub
```

Comment: Taskkiller works fine.. but text replacer don't work...
If i use "TextBox1.Text = list(i + 1)" Text after target line is shown in textbox1 but if i use "list(i + 1) = TextBox1.Text" text is not writen... :/

Comment: When you say written, do you mean written back in the text file?

Comment: Sorry my English is poor. I need the line after "/ / This Line" to Be replaced with other text. For example: Some command to write (i + 1) = "New text here"

Comment: so if I understand correctly you want to keep the line with the text "//This line" and write the "New text here" below it. So in the list you want to see, list(1) = "//This line", 2) list(2) = Textbox1.Text. Is that correct?

Comment: Still can't write that line... i can only read it... here is the source code: http://www.mediafire.com/?zuz4e45sff16944

Comment: I am assuming you want to write the list back in the text file. If that is the case you have to use File.WriteAllLines() method to do that. See in the update section above.